# Can a Wallet Generated by Linux Multibit Client be Used with Windows Multibit client?

Tags: multibit

Probably a stupid question.

I am planning to create cold storage using Multibit on Ubuntu LiveCD, get the wallet file out of it and store it securely.

In future if I use a Windows PC with Multibit and use the cold storage wallet file with it, should it work fine? Or the wallet file structure are different for Linux and Windows Multibit clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, if it didn't it would be a bug anyways. Linux and Windows Multibit should work properly on the same backup.